# Wordpress child theme css priority

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I edited my Wordpress style.css in the child theme folder but the CSS is not overriding unless I uses `!important` on everything.

How can I set the child theme `style.css` to a higher priority.
I already searched on Google and tried multiple solutions but somehow I don't get it working.

Comment: You'll need to give us an example. For all we know, you might **not be using** the same selector or a selector with a higher specificity to override styles. You might be attempting to override `element > .selector` with `.selector` in your child theme, which wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try dequeueing the child CSS in the child theme's functions.php and then enqueuing it with the parent theme's CSS as a dependency.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/